# Create a sitemap of the directory tree of website from a link

Tags: sitemap

After trying all the online services I haven't been able to create a sitemap of the following link (for which http://amd.cdn.example.com/adultswim/episodes//us_geo/ should be the starting point)

http://amd.cdn.example.com/adultswim/episodes/us_geo/dragonballzkai/2016/02/dragonballzkai_cc_059/cc_sidecars/dragonballzkai_cc_059_hls_webvtt.vtt

Why is it so, and what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! We do not allow new users to create links to their own site here. However, I do get the importance of having the link in your question. I have edited your question to remove the domain name. If a user needs to see the original link, they can simply review the edit history to get it. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc what does "http://amd.cdn." mean then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I simply changed the domain name to example which is our standard here. Anyone who needs to see the link can do so easily by looking at the edit history. In this way, we are preserving your question and still adhering to the standards set for this site. Our user often look at edit histories to help diagnose the situation.

Comment: @closetnoc technically, what does "domain name" refer to?

Comment: I changed turner.com to example.com.

Answer (score 2):

The links you provide give both the same error

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   "http://amd.cdn.example.com/adultswim/episodes/us_geo/" on this server.
>
> Reference #18.5f221502.1574092192.186833f

Try to make your website public before using Sitemap Generators otherwise they are not able to crawl your website.

Comment: use an online vpn https://proxy-nyc.hidemyass-freeproxy.com/proxy/es-es/aHR0cDovL2FtZC5jZG4udHVybmVyLmNvbS9hZHVsdHN3aW0vZXBpc29kZXMvdXNfZ2VvL2RyYWdvbmJhbGx6a2FpLzIwMTYvMDIvZHJhZ29uYmFsbHprYWlfY2NfMDU5L2NjX3NpZGVjYXJzL2RyYWdvbmJhbGx6a2FpX2NjXzA1OV9obHNfd2VidnR0LnZ0dA

Comment: the problem is online sitemap generator wont be able to use an online vpn and with denied access neither generate your sitemap